# Yii2 oauth sendRequest post in json

Tags: php, oauth, yii2

can I write like this?but it doesn't work.

```
public function generateParaQrCode($type = 2)
{
    $accessToken = $this->getAccessTokenWinXinPub();
    $acctionName = $this->getQrCodeType(3);
    $temp = str_random(64);
    $data = [
        'action_name' => $acctionName,
        'action_info' => [
            'scene' => ["scene_str" => $temp],
        ]
    ];
    $dataString = json_encode($data);



    return $this->sendRequest('POST', 'https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/qrcode/create?access_token='.$accessToken,
        [
            'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS' => $dataString,
            'CURLOPT_POST' => 1,
        ],[
            'Content-type: application/json;charset="utf-8"',
    ]);

}
```

This is yii2 application ,I use the yii\authclient\OAuth2 and extends it,but when I call this function ,it doesn't work.

Comment: $this->sendRequest() can use like up

Comment: "It doesn't work" is too vague. You need to provide the _actual_ error message you receive.

Comment: this is chinese app weChat ,it's said that my params error,but my params are express，but I know it's require post in json,so I use $this->sendRequest('POST', 'https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/qrcode/create?access_token='.$accessToken,
        [
            'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS' => $dataString,
            'CURLOPT_POST' => 1,
        ],[
            'Content-type: application/json;charset="utf-8"',
    ]);

Comment: "It said that my params error" - Does this code even build? Can you step through it? Can you check the HTTP response? Nobody is able to replicate your problem with the code you've provided. Update your question with the *actual error* you receive.